# Font does not work in the application written by ActionScript on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I wrote an application with Action Script 3 to run on Android!Persian Fonts are true when running in the Windows operating system environment.
but when i export in Android , Persian font dose not work!!i embedded Font and a lot of things i did it but it is not successful.
the code is in bellow!

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 
var t1:TextField=new TextField(); 

t1.text="سیدمحمدحسینی";
var tf:TextFormat=new TextFormat("F_titr",16,null,null,null,null,null,null,"right");
tf.align=TextFormatAlign.RIGHT;
var t2:TextField=new TextField();
t2.x=150;
t2.y=200;
t2.type=TextFieldType.INPUT;
t2.border=true;
t2.defaultTextFormat=tf;
addChild(t2);
var b1:button1=new button1();
b1.x=250;
b1.y=200;
addChild(b1);
b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,bb);
function bb(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if(t2.text==t1.text){
        t2.x=250;
        trace("ok");
    }else{
        t2.x=50;
        trace("no OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: In order for embedded fonts to display correctly the property **TextField.embedFonts** should be set to **true** for the relevant **TextField** instances: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#embedFonts

Comment: Dear i did it but when i run it on android the virtual keyboard disabled.

Comment: No, you did not. You might have embedded fonts into your SWF, but your code clearly shows you don't set the **.embedFonts = true;** for any of text fields you create.

Comment: OK dear! you right but when i add (t2.embed Font=true), in windows environment can not type any things too.so i have to clear it !!!!